# Dynamically change post_parent in every page load?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, actions

What's the correct Wordpress action where I can hook to dynamically change the post_parent of a post? I understand that a post can't have multiple parents so that's the only way I can think of to assign multiple parents to all posts(custom post type actually). I'm actually just modifying the behavior of a plugin so doing this via tags/categories is not an option. Preferably, I'd like to be able to change it before any query(for a post) has been initiated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/ ?

it allows to link a post or page to multiple other post or pages

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I need.